# How to replace text in UITextView with selected range?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, replace, uitextview

I want to replace the text in UITextView text in selected range. This is my question. Here i mention what i did? and what i want to do?. I have an UITextView and entered the below text in textview.

`Ask question here`, i have saved the range in of the text in textview. The text range is `{17, 0}`. I take the NSRange in `-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` delegate.

Now i want to replace the text `question` with `answer` and i want to replace the text `here` with `them. The UITextView.text look like this,`Ask answer them` after replaced the texts.

How can i replace the texts with the selected ranges? Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... I'm not sure to understand correctly what you're trying to do, but if your goal is to change some characters in a selected range you can follow these steps:

Get your UITextView content and put it in a NSString:

```
NSString *textViewContent = textView.text;
```

Change the characters in the range you want:

```
NSString *newContent = [textViewContent stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:replacement];
```

Replace old content with new one:

```
textView.text = newContent;
```

Anyway if you just want to replace **Ask question here** with **Ask answer them** the fastest solution is just:

```
textView.text = @"Ask answer them";
```

Answer (score 16):

Since iOS 7 there is the textStorage in the textView that inherits from `NSMutableAttributedString` so you can use those methods:

**Objective-C**

```c
[self.textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withString:];
```

or

```c
[self.textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:];
```

**Swift**

```swift
textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

Comment: I was looking through many of answers but this is the only one which helped me to avoid textView from autoscrolling to top every time I change text in it. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well solution from top of my head..

```
NSArray *Dividedstring = [[self.TextView.text] componentsSeparatedByString:@" question here "]; // this will divide the string into two parts ..one before question here and second after question here.
NSString  * firstpart = [Dividedstring objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString  * secondpart = [Dividedstring objectAtIndex:0];

self.TextView.text = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@ answer here %@",firstpart,secondpart];
```